# Django ModelForm - name 'Article' is not defined

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have something like this

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article

def articl(request):
    tykul = ArticleForm()
    return render_to_response('test.html',{'tykul':tykul.as_ul()})
```

And this is a result - name 'Article' is not defined

this same f.ex. for model = Book 
and others from ModelForm

Why ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you defined an `Article` model somewhere? Usually it's in `models.py` in the same folder as your `forms.py` and `views.py`, e.g.:

```
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField()
```

Of course, you'll have to import the `Article` model in your `forms.py`:

```
from models import Article
```

Comment: ok thanks, i thought that if this is FormModel it is making everything by itself

Answer (score 2):

You never imported any classes named Article or Book. They have to be defined in the namespace before they're used.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you'd define Article and Book in your models.py file, so `from models import Article, Book` need to go in your forms code.